# .NET AutoComplete DropDownList or TextBox on Mobile Web Browser?

Tags: c#, ajax, windows-mobile, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build an AutoComplete DropDown List that will work on a Mobile Browser (Pocket IE, Opera Mobile, etc.)  So for example, if I had one for US States, after typing in 'Ma', I'd expect to see 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massacusetts' as selectable options

I've been able to build one for a traditional browser with no issues, using both 3rd party tools (Telerik RadControls) and using basic AJAX components (scriptmanager, textbox, and autocompleteextender), but haven't had any success on a mobile platform.

What seems to be the problem in my opinion is the mobile framework seems to be limited when it comes to javascript and AJAX support.

Am I missing something?  Has anyone had any success with a project like this before?

Thanks for any suggestions.

~Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work on mobile browsers that support AJAX such as the opera mini.